# Sum up how many fields are empty or do not exist in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a problem. I have a list `myList` inside these list, there a dictionaries. I want to count if the field `dataOriginSystem` is empty or does not exist. Unfortunately I got the wrong result. `if(key_nested == 'dataOriginSystem'): ... else: count =+ 1`

The reason for this lies in the if-query. Since I am asking, does the field exist? If no, then count it up and since I loop through all the nested keys, one of the errors is here. Also, is there a way to make this more efficient?

How can I query how many of the field `dataOriginSystem` are empty or non-existent?

```py
count = 0
for element in myList:
    for key in element.keys():
        if(key == 'metaData'):
            for key_nested in element[key].keys(): 
                if(key_nested == 'dataOriginSystem'):
                    if(key_nested == None):
                        count += 1
                else:
                    count += 1
print(count)
```

```py
myList = [
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
},
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
 },
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
 },
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': None,
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
 },
]
```

Result should be

```
[OUT] 2
# Because of the two last elements.
# The first element does not exist
# and the second ist None.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to loop through the keys. Access the item you want directly and increment the counter if the item is not found, or found but None.

```
count = 0
for element in myList:
    if element["metaData"].get("dataOriginSystem", None) is None:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) directly on the nested key, returning a default value of `None`, and then count the number of `None` values you get:

```py
sum(d['metaData'].get('dataOriginSystem', None) is None for d in myList)
```

Output

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this...

```
non_existant = len([0 for item in myList if item['metaData'].get('dataOriginSystem') == None or item['metaData'].get('dataOriginSystem') == ''])
print(non_existant)
```

Output...

```
2
```